# Update slider based on info from another slider matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

I draw a line with origin at (0,0) and the second point at (10, yval) and use a slider to define the angle of a line and with this angle I compute a new "yval" and redraw the line.  This works great.

I added a second slider so that the user can define the "angle" (first slider) or the "yval" (second slider). When one or the other value changes I want the value of the other slider to change.

This works, partially.  If I move the angle slider first, everything is great.  But then when I try to move the yval slider, it freezes.  If I re-run the code and move the yval slider first, everything is again great. But then when I try to move the angle slider, it again freezes.

This has me stumped and I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks.

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider  # import the Slider widget

## def update(val): 
def update(val):
    global old_Angle, old_yval

# Define incoming values
    new_Angle = svalue_a.val
    new_yval = svalue_y.val
    Bx = 10

# Determine which slider changed
    if (new_Angle != old_Angle):
        old_Angle = new_Angle
        By = 10*np.tan(new_Angle * torad)
        # Reseat the yval slider due to change in angle slider
        slider2_ax.clear() #Clear the axis
        svalue_y.__init__(slider2_ax, 'yval', 0, 25, valinit=By)
    else:
        old_yval = new_yval
        new_Angle = np.arctan(new_yval/10)/torad
        By = new_yval
        # Reseat the angle slider due to change in yval slider
        slider_ax.clear() #Clear the axis
        svalue_a.__init__(slider_ax, 'angle', 20, 60, valinit=new_Angle)

    line.set_xdata((0, Bx))
    line.set_ydata((0, By))

    old_yval = By
    old_Angle = new_Angle

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()      

#Define and plot the triangle
def plot_triangle():
    plt.axes() #Select the main axis
    WAngle = 20.
    xmax = 10
    ymax = 10
    x1 = 0
    y1 = 0
    x2 = xmax
    y2 = y1
    x3 = xmax
    y3 = x3*np.tan(WAngle * torad)
    points = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]]
    plt.xlim(x1,xmax)
    plt.ylim(y1,ymax)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(points, facecolor='0.9', edgecolor='0.5')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)

# ############################################
#            Main program
# ############################################
fig, main_ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

#Some constants
torad = np.pi/180

# Initial values
old_Angle = 30

# Plot a triangle
plttri = plot_triangle()

#Now define the line and plot it
Bx = 10
By = Bx*np.tan(old_Angle * torad)
old_yval = By
line = plt.Line2D((0,Bx),(0,By))  #(x1,x2),(y1,y2)  
plt.gca().add_line(line)    

# Slider info
#[left, bottom, wide, high]
slider_ax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, .5, .03])
slider2_ax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.10, .5, .03])    
svalue_a = Slider(slider_ax, 'angle', 20, 60, valinit=old_Angle)    
svalue_y = Slider(slider2_ax, 'yval', 5, 17, valinit=old_yval)

svalue_a.on_changed(update)
svalue_y.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your yval slider and angle slider basically do the same thing, but your yval value depends on the angle slider, right?

Comment: Functionally, yes.  I use the angle slide to define an angle and I compute yval and the yval slider gives me the yval from which I compute an angle to update the slider.  The two sliders are therefor linked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinitializing the Slider, try changing the `init` value and reset the slider. That is what worked for me.

```
################################################
svalue_y.valinit = By
svalue_y.reset()
##################################################        
#slider2_ax.clear() #Clear the axis
#svalue_y.__init__(slider2_ax, 'yval', 0, 25, valinit=By)
    else:
old_yval = new_yval
new_Angle = np.arctan(new_yval/10)/torad
By = new_yval
# Reseat the angle slider due to change in yval slider
##################################################        
svalue_a.valinit = new_Angle
svalue_a.reset()
##################################################        
#slider_ax.clear() #Clear the axis
#svalue_a.__init__(slider_ax, 'angle', 20, 60, valinit=new_Angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I added function call to function `update` in the function itself, it worked fine.

```
def update(val):
global old_Angle, old_yval


new_Angle = svalue_a.val
new_yval = svalue_y.val
Bx = 10


if (old_yval != new_yval) : 
    old_yval = new_yval
    new_Angle = np.arctan(new_yval/10)/torad
    By = new_yval
    # Reseat the angle slider due to change in yval slider
    slider_ax.clear() #Clear the axis
    svalue_a.__init__(slider_ax, 'angle', 20, 60, valinit=new_Angle)

if (old_Angle != new_Angle):
    old_Angle = new_Angle
    By = 10*np.tan(new_Angle * torad)
    # Reseat the yval slider due to change in angle slider
    slider2_ax.clear() #Clear the axis
    svalue_y.__init__(slider2_ax, 'yval', 0, 25, valinit=By)


line.set_xdata((0, Bx))
line.set_ydata((0, By))

old_yval = By
old_Angle = new_Angle

fig.canvas.draw_idle()

svalue_a.on_changed(update)  #THIS LINE
svalue_y.on_changed(update)  #AND THIS LINE
```

With this line the code does what you want, but there are some other minor issues regarding visual look of the sliders, which shouldn't be an issue.

Also, you don't need to use the variable `plttri` to store return value from function `plot_triangle()` because that function has no return value.

Edit : I'd also reconsider the need for two sliders which basically do the same thing. I don't know your specific use case and why you need it the way you've done it, but it is something worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. This worked, but not entirely.  I put the two lines in, but if I continue to slide each of the sliders it eventually will freeze, and as you said, there are a lot of errors, which I do not know how to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the plttri.  I was not aware of this.  Also, you are correct, this is a subset of a more complicated problem.   I have a function of two variables z = f(x,y) so I would like two sliders so I can vary x and y independently and so see the value of z.

Comment: Did you try perhaps singling out update functions for each slider, e.g. update_yval and update_angle function which would call each other?

Answer (score 0):

after initializing each slider:

```
.__init__(
```

it must be redefine process

```
.onchange(update)
```

It works fine.